# bundler, rubygems and dynamic use of gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm developing a gem with uses bundler for its dependency management.

Now I want to use some gems but only when they are already installed in the system (shown by gem list), so I cannot add them to the Gemfile. Doing a simple

```
require("rmagick")
```

does not work because bundler seems to hide all gems not listed in the Gemfile. A simple test.rb without bundler and just containing

```
require "rubygems"
require "rmagick
```

works without any problems.

Anybody knows how to require a gem which is not listed in the Gemfile?

Comment: just was about to ask the same question, this would be really helpful to load debugging gems in an production environment (e.g. rails console)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to include it in your `Gemfile`, or include it prior to using `bundler`. If you include it after you get an error. There may be a way to turn that off but I can't find it.